# Create remmina connection file with saved password

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, vnc-viewer

I'm working on a C# app that starts a VNC connection to the Windows PC from a raspberry pi with a click of a button using remmina on the Rpi.

Note : there is no keyboard and mouse connected to the Rpi and things should happen all from pc (so remmina shouldn't ask for IP or Password at all).

this is my workaround to this :

1. start a SSH connection from PC to the Rpi.
2. Make a .remmina connection file
3. start remmina using that file

all the above stages are fine and I can do them without a problem
the point is creating the VNC password stored in the .remmina file

so the question is how can I encrypt the plain text “VNC password” to the encrypted remmina format?

also, I found some python scripts to Decrypt remmina password but didn't see anything in reverse.
and I tried encrypting using .net and c# but the result was different and didn't work.

> Update: this is the python script that Decrypts the password using
>   secret of remmina , this outputs 333333

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

secret = base64.decodestring('9c+QkAz49dY5PIuphZjJWFQwq72tvcwD4/QXFtxIkNE=')
password = base64.decodestring('Rk/hk6y5CmE=')

print DES3.new(secret[:24], DES3.MODE_CBC, secret[24:]).decrypt(password)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Fourat tried DES3 encryption to make password but it is different from password in remmina

Comment: Please update your question and add details and code and errors if any.